# Negative array size exception thrown by Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Recently my copy of eclipse ceased to live, though I can't think of what I may have done to cause this, I must have done something, but essentially for any work space I try to open the following shows up in my log files:

```
eclipse.buildId=M20120208-0800
java.version=1.7.0_04
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2012-08-29 09:30:43.361
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.TableReader.readArray(TableReader.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.TableReader.basicLoadExtensionPoint(TableReader.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.TableReader.loadExtensionPoint(TableReader.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.TableReader.loadExtensionPointTree(TableReader.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.RegistryObjectManager.load(RegistryObjectManager.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.RegistryObjectManager.basicGetObject(RegistryObjectManager.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.RegistryObjectManager.getObject(RegistryObjectManager.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.BaseExtensionPointHandle.getExtensionPoint(BaseExtensionPointHandle.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.BaseExtensionPointHandle.getExtensions(BaseExtensionPointHandle.java:32)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.activities.ws.TriggerPointManager.<init>(TriggerPointManager.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.activities.ws.WorkbenchActivitySupport.<init>(WorkbenchActivitySupport.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.init(Workbench.java:1523)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$36(Workbench.java:1486)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$66.run(Workbench.java:2597)
```

I tried looking for this error, and I found a few references to negative array size exceptions in the eclipse bugs forums, but nothing that seemed to be related to this.Any ideas?

Comment: Does this happen for new workspaces as well as already existing ones?

Comment: That would suggest to me that one of the installed plugins is causing this error. If you're curious and the old install is still there, you could scan your computer for files modified since the last known working date. However, to just get it working again, I recommend a reinstall (which you seem to be doing already).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running `eclipse -clean` to clean out your configuration area.  Perhaps something got corrupted.  This will likely fix your problem.

Comment: wouldn't run, CLI was broken too apparently. Assume something just got corrupted and so I'm just re installing everything.